# ¿Por que no me llegan los POST?

Tags: javascript

Tengo la solicitud ( la ruta es por un ruteo que cree ) y ya comprobe que si esta accediendo al metodo especificado

```
var formulario = document.getElementById('registrar');
    if(formulario){
        console.log("hola");
        formulario.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let datos = new FormData(formulario);
            let nombre = document.getElementById('nombre');
            console.log("da : ", nombre.value);
            fetch('index.php?url=SolicitudController/store' , {
                method: 'POST',
                data: nombre.value
            })
            .catch(error => {
                error.message = 'Error  :'+ error; 
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Respuesta " + data);
            });
        });
```

Luego en php en mi controlador me imprime el arreglo vacio, no me llega nada por post.No entiendo por que, crei que era un mal uso del FormData, por eso cree una sola variable para solo recibir el input de nombre, pero aun asi, aunque imprimpo antes de enviar y me da el valor.Del lado de php no me llegan los post.
echo var_dump("El post: " , $_POST);

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` no es una opción correcta para [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), debes usar `body` en su lugar

```
fetch('index.php?url=SolicitudController/store' , {
    method: 'POST',
    body: nombre.value
})
```

La opción `body` acepta un string, json, blob y Formadata (entre [otros](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#body)), por lo que también puedes hacer

```
let datos = new FormData(formulario);
fetch('index.php?url=SolicitudController/store' , {
    method: 'POST',
    body: datos 
})
```